# Nodejs Brotli compression returning zeros

Tags: javascript, node.js, memcached, brotli

I’m trying to store large database query results in a memcached server for quicker retrieval, and am compressing the data prior to entry in memcache with [brotli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/brotli).

I’ve been trying to test with an example object like so:

```js
//cacheserver already defined and connected
let brotli_config = {
    mode: 1, //0=regular, 1=text
    quality: 8 //1=fast .. 11=small
}

let test_key = 'paths_100'
let test_value = [
    {
        text: 'this is text',
        outlines: 'this is an outline',
        inlines: 'this is an inline'
    }
]

let compressed_in = require('brotli/compress')(JSON.stringify(test_value), brotli_config)
console.log(compressed_in) //LOG 1
cacheserver.set(test_key, compressed_in, {
        expires: 3600
    },
    function(err) {
        cacheserver.get(test_key, function(err, compressed_out) {
            console.log(compressed_out) //LOG 2

            let string_out = require('brotli/decompress')(compressed_out)
            console.log(string_out) //LOG 3
        })
    }
)
```

And this is the output:

```
//LOG 1
Uint8Array(10) [
  27, 86,   0,  0, 36,
   0,  2, 177, 64, 32
]

//LOG 2
<Buffer 1b 56 00 00 24 00 02 b1 40 20>

//LOG 3
Uint8Array(87) [
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0
]
```

I’m turning the object into a string (probably not a good idea for performance, but using brotli mode 0 and not stringifying wasn’t working; returning null...), compressing it, storing the 10-entry uint8array in the cache server, retrieving a 10-byte buffer, and decompressing it. However, the decompressed result is just an array of zeros. What’s happening here? I’m using this compression library and the memcached client (**memjs**) for the first time, so any information on how to properly use them is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a solution (let me know if it could be sped up). Many thanks to [this blog post](https://www.codelime.blog/convert-between-strings-buffers-and-objects-in-nodejs/#Convert-Object-to-Buffer) for clarifying the relationship between nodejs objects, strings, and buffers.

I was missing a conversion from a string to a buffer before passing the object data to brotli. The full procedure looks like this now:

```js
let data = {/* stuff */}
let test_key = 'paths_100'
let compressed_in = require('brotli/compress')(Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(test_value),'utf-8'), brotli_config)
cacheserver.set(test_key, compressed_in, {
        expires: 3600
    },
    function(err) {
        cacheserver.get(test_key, function(err, compressed_out) {
            let data_out = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(require('brotli/decompress')(compressed_out)).toString('utf-8'))
        })
    }
)
```